Proving that a Category is Well Powered
I am studying the Special Adjoint Functor Theorem, and one of the things we need to verify in order to apply it is if a category is well-powered (each object admits a small poset of subobjects). In most places I look, everyone says that it is a trivially verified condition. But sometimes it is not that obvious to me.
For example, how do I prove that the category of Sup (the category of complete partially ordered set with supremum, and functions that preserves supremums) is well-powered?
Any help, or tips are really appreciated!!

Have you calculated what the subobjects are?

@Trebor Are the subobjects maps that send supremums to supremums?

Subobjects in $\mathbf{Sup}$ are exactly what you would expect them to be (namely, they correspond to the subsets closed under supremums).
